# Java client to WCF service interop with mutual certificate - Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature

Tags: java, wcf, interop, x509certificate, x509

**Exception:
MessageSecurityException: Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature: KeyInfo 'SecurityKeyIdentifier**

I have to set up a WCF service to receive SOAP calls from a Java client that is sending signed content with the following header:

```
<soap:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-2">
    <ds:SignedInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
      <ds:Reference URI="#id-3" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:Transforms xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        <ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">…</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
      <ds:Reference URI="#Timestamp-1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <ds:Transforms xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
        <ds:DigestValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">…</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      …
    </ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-66FC0491F2BB65AFF813274134607712" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="...." xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <ds:X509Data xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <ds:X509IssuerSerial xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:X509IssuerName xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">CN=XXXXXXXX</ds:X509IssuerName>
            <ds:X509SerialNumber xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">111122222</ds:X509SerialNumber>
          </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
        </ds:X509Data>
      </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="Timestamp-1">
    <wsu:Created>xxxxx</wsu:Created>
    <wsu:Expires>xxxx</wsu:Expires>
  </wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soap:Header>
```

**I have tried setting up the following binding and behavior:**

```
      <customBinding>
    <binding name="javaclientBinding">
      <security
        defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic256Rsa15" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
        allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
        authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex"
        requireDerivedKeys="false"
        securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast"
        allowInsecureTransport="true"
        requireSignatureConfirmation="false"
        requireSecurityContextCancellation="false">
      </security>
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>



<behavior name="javaclientBehavior">
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
<serviceCredentials>
    <clientCertificate>
    <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust"/>
</clientCertificate>
<serviceCertificate
    findValue="applicationServer"
  storeLocation="CurrentUser"
  storeName="My"
  x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
</serviceCredentials>
   </behavior>
```

**But I get the following exception in the servers event log:**

```
ClientIdentity: 
   ActivityId: <null>
   MessageSecurityException: Cannot resolve KeyInfo for verifying signature: KeyInfo
  'SecurityKeyIdentifier
   (
       IsReadOnly = False,
       Count = 1,
       Clause[0] = X509IssuerSerialKeyIdentifierClause(Issuer = 'CN=XXXXXX)
    )
   ', available tokens 'SecurityTokenResolver
(
TokenCount = 0,
)
```

'.

We have to get signature validation working, and we have no possibility to change what the java client is sending.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I'm having the same problem, and i'm using the aproach suggested by Yaron Naveh.

I haven't finished yet, but I'm making some advances (I'll post a full answer when I finish).

The request uses an AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement, not a SymmetricSecurityBindingElement as Yaron suggested.

The Inclusion Mode  of the X509SecurityTokenParameters should be set to SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator

The binding should look like this

```
//Only the following MessageSecurityVersion are asimetric: 

//WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10
//WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10

AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement abe =(AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)
SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(    
  MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10);

abe.SetKeyDerivation(false);

X509SecurityTokenParameters x509ProtectionParameters =
    new X509SecurityTokenParameters(X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial);

x509ProtectionParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToInitiator;
x509ProtectionParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial;

abe.InitiatorTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
abe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
abe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDesRsa15;

HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding = new CustomBinding(abe, httpBinding);
return binding;
```

I hope this helps a bit

Comment: Using this binding i'm being able to generate a similar request to the one of your question, but when I put this same binding on WCF service, I'm getting the same error. I'm stuck right now

Answer (score 0):

please publish the whole request envelope here.

Generally in such cases I suggest to build a WCF client first and verify that it works. You could build a WCF client that sends a serial number like this:

```
SymmetricSecurityBindingElement messageSecurity = new SymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
X509SecurityTokenParameters x509ProtectionParameters = 
                new X509SecurityTokenParameters( X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial);
messageSecurity.ProtectionTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
HttpTransportBindingElement httpBinding = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
Binding binding = new  CustomBinding(messageSecurity, httpBinding);
```

note the usage of X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial. Possibly creating a server via a custom binding with this setting will solve the whole issue, but I suggest to start wcf to wcf.

Comment: Thanks for your help, added full header now.

Comment: We have gotten a wcf client to send the same xml as the java client, so we were optimistic that we were getting there, but we are still stuck.

We have a ServiceHost factory method similar to this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702627.aspx

Comment: please publish the full wcf failing request and the full java working request (from the Enevelope tag)

Comment: Hello, the working request has been using a Binary Security Token, like described in this blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dhrubach/archive/2010/06/18/10027513.aspx

Comment: afaiu the problem now is that the response contains a reference and not a BST. then your hope is to pre process the response before wcf does and replace the reference with a bst. this should be possible since the  key reference part is not signed, so no problem to change it. also I assume you know what the bst is since you should know what the current serial number reference relates to. you can use something similar to a wcf stripping channel: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/371184de-5c05-4c70-8899-13536d8f5d16